# Why did this weird happen to me in File Explorer in Win 10, and how do I reverse it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

File Explorer and weird? Explain.

As shown in the pic below, the columns that usually show the specs have suddenly disappeared in one of my folders.

This problem is only in this folder, and in no other. It suddenly occurred when I clicked somewhere randomly. The specs columns disappeared almost immediately.

[image: Problem!]

Below is an example of how the specs columns normally look like. It shows the different properties of the file like the size, file type, last modified among others.

[image: Normal]

Some specs about the operating system and the machine?

Laptop - Acer Aspire 3

Windows version - NT10

Answer (score 2):

You've changed the view from *Details* to *List*. Use the ribbon (collapsed toolbar at the top) to change the view back.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!